# how to override an application property programatically in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, testcontainers

I've recently started using **testcontantainers** for unit/integration testing database operations in my Quarkus webapp. It works fine except I cannot figure out a way to dynamically set the MySQL port in the `quarkus.datasource.url` application property. Currently I'm using the deprecated `withPortBindings` method to force the containers to bind the exposed MySQL port to port *11111* but the right way is to let testcontainers pick a random one and override the `quarkus.datasource.url` property.

My unit test class

```java
    @Testcontainers
    @QuarkusTest
    public class UserServiceTest {
      @Container
      private static final MySQLContainer MY_SQL_CONTAINER = (MySQLContainer) new MySQLContainer()
          .withDatabaseName("userServiceDb")
          .withUsername("foo")
          .withPassword("bar")
          .withUrlParam("serverTimezone", "UTC")
          .withExposedPorts(3306)
          .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd ->
              ((CreateContainerCmd) cmd).withHostName("localhost")
                .withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(11111), new ExposedPort(3306)))  // deprecated, let testcontainers pick random free port
          );
      
      @BeforeAll
      public static void setup() {
        // TODO: use the return value from MY_SQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl()
        // to set %test.quarkus.datasource.url
        LOGGER.info(" ********************** jdbc url = {}", MY_SQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());
      }
      // snip...
    }
```

my application.properties:

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:11111/userServiceDb?serverTimezone=UTC
%test.quarkus.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=foo
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=bar
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

The [Quarkus guide to configuring an app](https://quarkus.io/guides/config) describes how to programmatically read an application property:

```java
String databaseName = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("database.name", String.class);
```

but not how to set it. [This tutorial](https://ilhicas.com/2020/02/14/Quarkus-Testcontainers.html) on using test containers with Quarkus implicates it should be possible:

*// Below should not be used - Function is deprecated and for simplicity of test , You should override your properties at runtime*

**SOLUTION:**
As suggested in the accepted answer, I don't have to specify host and port in the datasource property. So the solution is to simply replace the two lines in application.properties:

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:11111/userServiceDb
%test.quarkus.datasource.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

with

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:///userServiceDb
%test.quarkus.datasource.driver=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

(and remove the unnecessary `withExposedPorts` and `withCreateContainerCmdModifier` method calls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the documentation carefully. The port can be omitted.

https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I updated my question with the specific solution for my case.

Answer (score 2):

now (quarkus version **19.03.12**) it can be a bit simpler.

1. Define test component that starts container and overrides JDBC props

```java
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public class PostgresDatabaseResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    public static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> DATABASE = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:10.5")
            .withDatabaseName("test_db")
            .withUsername("test_user")
            .withPassword("test_password")
            .withExposedPorts(5432);

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        DATABASE.start();
        return Map.of(
                "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url", DATABASE.getJdbcUrl(),
                "quarkus.datasource.db-kind", "postgresql",
                "quarkus.datasource.username", DATABASE.getUsername(),
                "quarkus.datasource.password", DATABASE.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        DATABASE.stop();
    }
}
```

2. use it in test

```java
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(PostgresDatabaseResource.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void myAwesomeControllerTestWithDb() {
      // whatever you want to test here. Quarkus will use Container DB
      given().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(blaBla)
                .when().post("/create-some-stuff").then()
                .statusCode(200).and()
                .extract()
                .body()
                .as(YourBean.class);
      
    }
```